# Retrieve data USB harddisk with I/O problem

Tags: usb, hard-drive, io

I am having trouble with a USB drive.

It is a 2.5", 2TB spinner, that connects over usb.

It is used between operating systems (windows 10 and ubuntu)
Since a couple of days it starting giving trouble that has gotten worse.

If i dmesg

```
[  211.077565] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  211.099356] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2322, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  211.099360] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  211.099362] usb 2-3: Product: Expansion
[  211.099364] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  211.099366] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: NA8D6HFL
[  211.681898] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  211.687750] scsi host1: uas
[  211.687811] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  211.688197] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        9300 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6    
[  211.688760] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  211.688940] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[  212.725020] .............
[  226.037079] .............
[  239.348958] .........ready
[  247.541529] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 3907029167 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[  277.664526] sd 1:0:0:0: tag#3 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
[  277.664532] sd 1:0:0:0: tag#3 CDB: Mode Sense(6) 1a 00 3f 00 04 00
[  277.684542] scsi host1: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[  282.772710] usb 2-3: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[  287.892586] usb 2-3: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[  293.268637] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  298.644490] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  298.852507] usb 2-3: device not accepting address 2, error -62       
[  304.276456] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  309.652359] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  309.860352] usb 2-3: device not accepting address 2, error -62 
[  315.284350] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  320.660292] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  320.868254] usb 2-3: device not accepting address 2, error -62
[  326.292254] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  331.668149] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  331.876038] usb 2-3: device not accepting address 2, error -62
[  331.892552] scsi host1: uas_eh_device_reset_handler FAILED err -19
[  331.892563] sd 1:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[  331.892586] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  331.892649] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[  331.892654] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[  331.892668] sd 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  331.892675] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[  331.892677] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  331.892681] sd 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  331.892685] sd 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  331.892688] sd 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  331.892693] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[  332.244133] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR 
driverbyte=DRIVER_OK   
[  332.244139] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[  332.484019] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR 
driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  332.484024] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[  332.580124] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[  332.884115] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[  338.324098] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  343.700051] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  343.907982] usb 2-3: device not accepting address 3, error -62
[  349.331970] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  354.707903] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  354.915759] usb 2-3: device not accepting address 4, error -62
[  354.923860] usb usb2-port3: attempt power cycle
[  361.107794] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  366.483737] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  366.691684] usb 2-3: device not accepting address 5, error -62
[  372.115687] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  377.491594] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  377.699533] usb 2-3: device not accepting address 6, error -62
[  377.707547] usb usb2-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Is there a way to retrieve the data from the disk?
Is this a problem with the usb-SATA bridge or with the hardrive?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry David my bad. 20.04 LTS 64bit. I9 64 gb